# Android how to mange spinner with radio button in listview?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, spinner

My problem is that when I am clicking on radio button it will change the spinner value randomly at any position..please help here is my adapter class..

```
public class ManageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> _manageArrayList = null;
    private Context _Context = null;
    private Integer selectedPosition = 0;
    String List1[]=new String[]{"In use","Lost" ,"Stolen" , "For sale"};
    private int flag = 0;


    public ManageAdapter(ArrayList<String> _manageArrayList, Context _Context) {
        super();
        this._manageArrayList = _manageArrayList;
        this._Context = _Context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return _manageArrayList != null? _manageArrayList.size():0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView itemTextView;
        public RadioButton myitemButton;
        public Spinner inUseSpinner;
        public RelativeLayout managelayout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_Context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(v == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_single_row, null,false);
            holder.managelayout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.single_row_layout);
            holder.itemTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name_txt);
            holder.myitemButton = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.manage_radio_buton);
            holder.inUseSpinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.Status_spinner);
            v.setTag(holder);

            ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_Context,R.layout.spinner_color,List1);
            Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
            //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
            holder.inUseSpinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.itemTextView.setText(_manageArrayList.get(position));

        holder.inUseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // int getPosition = (Integer) arg0.getTag();
                //  Toast.makeText(_Context,List1[position] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        if(flag  == 0)
        {
            flag = 1;
            holder.myitemButton.setChecked(false);
            holder.myitemButton.setTag(position);
        }else {
            holder.myitemButton.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
            holder.myitemButton.setTag(position);
        }
        holder.myitemButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_item);

        _backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        _backButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _headerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_TextView);
        _headerTextView.setText("My Items");

        _uploadButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Upload_file_button);
        _uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _addmanullyButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_item_manually);
        _addmanullyButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _addphoneButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.auto_add_phone);
        _addphoneButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _modifyButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.modify_button);
        _modifyButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _transferButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.transfer_ownership);
        _transferButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        _hideenButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hideen_button);
        _hideenButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        _manageListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.manage_listview);
        prepareList();
        _adapter = new ManageAdapter(listItem, this);
        _manageListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
    }
    public void prepareList() {
        listItem = new ArrayList<String>();

        listItem.add("Android smart");
        listItem.add("sony");
        listItem.add("samsung");
        listItem.add("micromax");
        listItem.add("tablet");
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.Upload_file_button:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, UploadFileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.modify_button:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, ModifyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.transfer_ownership:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, TransferOwnerShip.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.add_item_manually:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, AddManuallyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.auto_add_phone:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, AutoAddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.back:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, MenuActivtiy.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.hideen_button:
            intent = new Intent(ManageItems.this, MenuActivtiy.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: You need t write setOnCheckedChangeListener listener for radiobutton instead of onclick

Comment: wait i will check it..

Comment: onCheckedchangeLisntener what sholud I do ?

Comment: like this holder.myitemButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
     selectedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();
    }
   }
  });

Comment: it not taking line selectedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag(); giving error on that ..

Comment: add fine before of view

Comment: use `selectedPosition = (Integer)buttonView.getTag()`...

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi change that line like gopal suggested..

Comment: @kalyan are getting my problem ?

Comment: my problem is that when i change the value of spinner and then clicking on radio button then it show the value of spinner at any random postion..

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi got it..for this you need to maintain one core class and save radio button state..spinner position..

Comment: I am using this for the position of the clicked spinner if(parentPosition == position)
    {
     holder.myitemButton.setTag(position);
    }

Comment: i think this some what confusion..You are it in listview it will populate multiple views when scroll and getView method call again..so maintianing state is neccesdary for listview.so take one class with one integer and one boolean value and if any other variables based on your requirement and pass them in a arraylist to your adapter..whenever the spinner changed or radiobutton checked save those values in a core object and set them..

Comment: ok..have you changed your code as i said above..and tested??what happened??

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi once post your Activity code and R.layout.manage_single_row layout..

Comment: problem is that when I changed the spinner  value  after that when I am clicking on radio button It will also  reflcting the value of spinner randomly like If I changed 2 spinner value after clicking radio button it will shown on 5 position spinner..

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi ok..i understand your question..once post R.layout.manage_single_row..i will do and post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all but I got the solution of my question..

```
 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            MyItemListDataHolder myItemListDataHolder = _manageArrayList.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_Context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if(v == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_single_row, null,false);
                holder.managelayout = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.single_row_layout);
                holder.itemTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_name_txt);
                holder.myitemButton = (RadioButton)v.findViewById(R.id.manage_radio_buton);
                holder.inUseSpinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.Status_spinner);
                v.setTag(holder);

            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.itemTextView.setText(myItemListDataHolder.get_itemName());

            Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_Context,R.layout.spinner_color,List1);
            Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
            //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
            holder.inUseSpinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
            if(myItemListDataHolder.get_selectedItem() > 0){
                holder.inUseSpinner.setSelection(myItemListDataHolder.get_selectedItem());
            }else{
                holder.inUseSpinner.setSelection(0);
            }
            holder.inUseSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                private Intent intent;

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position1, long arg3) {
                    _manageArrayList.get(position).set_selectedItem(position1);
                    //  notifyDataSetChanged();
                    String status=holder.inUseSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Lost"))
                    {
                        intent = new Intent (_Context, LostItemActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Stolen")) {
                        intent = new Intent (_Context, StolenItemActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Stolen")) {
                        intent = new Intent (_Context, LostFoundActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

            if(flag  == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                holder.myitemButton.setChecked(false);
            }else {
                holder.myitemButton.setChecked(position == selectedPosition);
            }
            holder.myitemButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }
```